# Converting a GET parameter into a friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL: `www.example.co.uk/news-and-views/article.php?Id=name-of-article`

The index page of `news-and-views` simply spits out all news articles and a URL to view the article (which is the one above)

Basically `SELECT * FROM news`

Instead of `news-and-views/article.php?Id=name-of-article` I would like to remove the `article.php?Id=` so that the URL would simply be `news-and-views/name-of-article`

I know that in a .htaccess file you can do something like this:

`RewriteRule /(.*)/$ article.php?Id=$1`

But this didn't seem to work?

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You could also use a `POST` request if supported, then your parameters won't show up in the url, but be aware the parameters won't be passed when you call the url again. If that does not matter (e.g. when calling from a program), you can use `POST`

Answer (score 0):

Using this rule...

```
RewriteRule ^news-and-views/(.+) /news-and-views/article.php?Id=$1
```

...will masks URLs in the way you describe.

So going to `http://www.example.co.uk/news-and-views/test` would call `http://www.example.co.uk/news-and-views/article.php?Id=test` behind the scenes.

Comment: What happens if i then go to /news-and-views/ ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken it will mask that as `/news-and-views/article.php?Id=` - ie with empty id

Comment: What if I want to use news-and-views/ as a place to display all articles?

Comment: I've updated the rule to facilitate that. It will now ignore `/news-and-views/` so you can serve up whatever you want there in whatever way you prefer.

Comment: One more point... If I have a deeper news page like /blah/news-and-views/ would the same rule still apply?

Comment: It would not. It could. Would article.php still be in the root new folder?

Comment: Yes, essentially I'd have two places

example.com/news-and-views

and 

example.com/more-specific/news-and-views/